# How to append a text to a path in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I am working on the below code. Is it doable to append a text into `path` using jQuery?

```js
$("path").each(function() {
  $(this).append("<span>Title</span>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" fill="gold"/>
</svg>

<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" fill="gold"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I see a big yellow triangle.  Where do you want the text?

Comment: like in the center of each path

Comment: Horizontal paths? What size text?  Measured in pixels?  What font?  I see a 2nd yellow triangle when I scroll down.

Comment: Aside: I notice that a large number of your questions are formulated thus: _Can you please take a look at this [code|demo] and please let me know [problem statement]_. It's a bit fluffy, and readers may think that it has a needy, pleading feel. It may be why you are getting downvotes - your questions are imploring readers about all the actions you'd like them to take, in order to alleviate your well-advertised suffering. You may have a better response if you explain what actions _you_ will do - and that is probably appropriate, given that it is your code.

Comment: So, you can instead use more "I statements". For example, "I am working on the demo code below. How can I append a string to a path using jQuery?" Readers will see that you understand that the bulk of the work is yours to do, and thus will be more likely to help you. I acknowledge that you may not be trying to dump your work onto volunteers - the trick is to also sound like you are not doing that.